# How do I disable functions on servers for particular directories?

Tags: linux, php, security, php5

I want to disable some functions on server to improve security of server. I followed these steps:

**STEP: 1**
Open `php.ini` file:
  `vi /etc/php.ini`

**STEP: 2**
Find `disable_functions` and set new list as follows:
    disable_functions= exec,passthru,shell_exec,system

**STEP: 3**
    service httpd restart

With the help of above steps I am able to disable all the above functions. Now these functions are no longer available on server.

If I want to enable or disable these functions for particular directories then it is possible or not?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532987/disable-php-functions-within-htaccess

Answer (score 2):

No its not possible to do that in a reliable way.
As we stand, php does not provides an option to white-list certain directories for certain functions.
A custom function could be written that allows for the execution of the "forbidden" functions in certain directories, but that means you have to allow them globally, and that will not stop programmers to access the forbidden functions directly.

The disable_functions setting is only available inside php.ini, any other way to try and overwrite it is not allowed(for example: `ini_set` or through apache configs).

So really you have 2 options, use it, or not, but there is no inbetween.

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

And in particular this:

> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.

@slm
That is one strategy but that doesn't keep them from escalating out side of the directory, so it would really be a facade and obscure way to do it. Even if that will work.

Comment: are you 100% sure ?? Is there any alternate to achieve the same ??

Comment: Can you elaborate as to the reasons why? As it stands this answer may be correct but it doesn't provide any reasons as to why which would be helpful for the OP and others that may come across this answer in the future.

Comment: I have two servers suppose server A and server B. I use server A to convert voice file into another format and then I send it to server B.   I use exec function to convert voice file on server A. Now I want to disable exec function but if I do the same then I'll not be able to convert voice file into another format that's why I am asking is it possible to enable functions for particular directories?

Comment: expanded my comment for a bit

Answer (score -1):

I think you could turn this around and not disable the functions in your `php.ini` file but then disable them on a directory per directory basis in either a `.htaccess` file or your Apache `httpd.conf` file, if you're using Apache as your web server. Other web servers most likely offer this feature too.

According to this [blog post](http://www.techiezone.net/webmaster/how-to-overwrite-php-ini-settings-using-htacess/), you can override php flag and value settings in `php.ini` in your `.htaccess` file.

For example you could do the following:

```
# .htaccess in directory X
php_value disable_functions exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

-or- to re-enable it:

```
# .htaccess in directory X
php_value disable_functions null
```

The above is untested by me so I'm not sure if it will work for you or not. Also I can understand some of the confusion around this facility in `PHP`. According to the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) it doesn't sound like the above is possible outside of the `php.ini` file.

> disable_functions string
>
> This directive allows you to disable certain
>   functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of
>   function names. disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode.
>
> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive.
>   User-defined functions are unaffected.
>
> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this
>   in httpd.conf.

Comment: I tested this ...not working ..:(

Comment: It'll never work. Allowing `.htaccess` files to override the `diable_functions` setting would destroy the entire point of it for security.